# Customer segmentation: backward calculation

Tags: r, excel, linear-algebra, linear-programming

I am doing customer segmentation, each customer has 3 attributes X, Y and Z. Based on the values of these 3 attributes, I separate them into 6 groups, say A - F.

```
              X     Y     Z Group
John D.     300    35  1000     A
Adam S.     230    40  2500     B
Will Y.     500    55  3000     C
```

Then I count the number of customers falling into each group:

```
n(A) n(B) n(C) n(D) n(E) n(F)
5    5    20   30   20   20
```

Here is how I classify the customers based on x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2:

```
X               Y               Z       Group
>x1 and <=x2    <=y1            >z2     A
>x2             <=y1            >=0     A
<=x1            <=y1            >z2     B
>x1 and <=x2    <=y1            <=z2    B
>x1 and <=x2    >y1 and <=y2    >z2     C
>x2             >y1 and <=y2    >=0     C
<=x1            <=y1            <=z2    D
<=x1            >y1 and <=y2    >=0     D
>x1 and <=x2    >y1 and <=y2    <=z2    D
>x1 and <=x2    >y2             >z2     E
>x2             >y2             >=0     E
<=x1            >y2             >=0     F
>x1 and <=x2    >y2             <=z2    F
```

So that’s how I start from x1, x2,... to get n(A), n(B), n(C)...

What I want to do is to work backward from n(A), n(B), n(C), ..., n(F) to get x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2. (By changing only the numbers, the grouping rules in the table remain unchanged.)

I'm not even sure what type of problem I'm dealing with. I thought it was linear programming but I couldn't seem to formulate the problem.

Any ideas how I can solve this problem, in R or any other software?

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to cluster? Or if you have labelled data (i.e. you know what group each customer belongs to) you can use a decision tree.

Comment: Thanks Axeman. Yes working forward is like decision tree. The results would be percentages of customer in each group. But I don't know how to work backward, starting with the customer percentage and calculate the proper decision node.

Comment: @Lopavit I would (probably) know of a way of implementing this, but it's not clear to me from the original question what should be the individual attributes. Could you perhaps edit your question with a table that would look like `1. X <= 200; Y > 2; Z <= 1000; "A", 2. ...` ?  Basically I need an example of some input data and then the expected output. I can't really comprehend it out of your `R` code

Comment: @Rawrplus I have edited my question. Please take a look and let me know. Thank you!